# is it possible to send a query in database if the no. of likes are above 50

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a page in which user can upload their picture and other users can like it.

Now is there any method that when the user's like goes above 50 lets say 51, then execute a query that saves this users name and postid. And then show a notification to user that your post have crossed 50 likes.

Also i dont want the query to execute again and again i want it to send that query only once for that particular post i am using php any suggestions

this is the code that i used but didnt work:

```
<?php if ($vote>=50){
mysqli_query($con, "insert into notifications (user_id,post_id) values('$id3','$pixid')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you only need to run this code when number of vote is 51?

Comment: yes @KamalPaliwal

Comment: Then why don't you match this with 51 directly, like if($vote==51)

Comment: okk but that will not solve my problem every time ill refresh the page it will execute query @KamalPaliwal

Comment: I don't know where the query value variables are coming from, but they are "user-supplied" and both integers then you can cast both as `(int)` to avoid a prepared statement.  Otherwise, I recommend a prepared statement.

Comment: Make the `user_id` and `post_id` columns unique/primary keys so that the insert will fail.  When it fails, don't alert the poster.  Will that do?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below :

```
if($vote > 50) {
    $result = mysqli_query("select * from notifications where user_id = " . $id3 . " And post_id = " . $pixid);
    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        mysqli_query($con, "insert into notifications (user_id,post_id) values('$id3','$pixid')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid posting _try this_ / code-only answers.